# How to assign 2D int array to byte array in Dart?

Tags: arrays, dart

I have a DART 2 dimensional array defined as

```
     var matrix = List.generate(10, (i) =>List.filled(4, 0, growable: false),
          growable: false);
```

I can populate it with random numbers

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
        matrix[i][j] = random.nextInt(MaxRan);
        }
      }
```

I now want to process this array using various base64 and compression libraries. If I attempt to cast it to Uint8List

```
Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(matrix);
```

I receive a message saying "`The argument type 'List<List<int>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<int>'`".

How do I assign the list to a byte structure?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message indicates, `Uint8List` can be constructed from a `List<int>`, not from `List<List<int>>`.  You have a few options:

- Splice all of your sublists together into a single `List<int>` and then convert that to a `Uint8List`:

  ```dart
  var flattened = [for (var row in matrix) ...row];
  var bytes = Uint8List.fromList(flattened);
  ```
- Create a `Uint8List` with the total size and initialize its elements from each of the sublists:

  ```dart
  var bytes = Uint8List(matrix.length * matrix[0].length);
  var byteOffset = 0;
  for (var row in matrix) {
    for (var cell in row) {
      bytes[byteOffset] = cell;
      byteOffset += 1;
    }
  }
  ```
- You also could avoid extra copying by using a `Uint8List` in the first place and providing helper functions to access elements:

  ```dart
  class Matrix {
    final int rows;
    final int columns;

    final Uint8List data;

    Matrix({required this.rows, required this.columns})
        : data = Uint8List(rows * columns);

    int getIndex(int row, int column) {
      if (row < 0 || row >= rows) {
        throw RangeError('row $row not in range [0, $rows)');
      }
      if (column < 0 || column >= columns) {
        throw RangeError('column $column not in range [0, $columns)');
      }

      return row * columns + column;
    }

    int get(int row, int column) => data[getIndex(row, column)];

    void set(int row, int column, int value) =>
        data[getIndex(row, column)] = value;
  }

  void main() {
    var i = 0;
    var matrix = Matrix(rows: 10, columns: 4);
    for (var row = 0; row < matrix.rows; row += 1) {
      for (var column = 0; column < matrix.columns; column += 1) {
        matrix.set(row, column, i);
        i += 1;
      }
    }

    print(matrix.data);
  }
  ```